# simplifying formulas in maxima

Tags: maxima

I'm using maxima software to help me simplify formulas. Usually, I can manage easily with subst, ratsubst, factor, ratsimp, ... But there are still are few formulas I find hard to simplify the way I'd like to.

1. assuming that a > b and c > d, I'd like to simplify fractions starting with a - sign this way :

   ```
   -(a - b)/(d - c)    ->   ( a - b )/( c - d)
   ```

   but I don't how to do it. It seems that maxima simplifier algorithm
   will try to sort variables in its own way.

   I created my own maxima function to try to simplify these useless minus signs.

   ```
   no_minus(fraction):=
     block([simp:true,
        numerat:expand(-ratnumer(fraction)),
        denominat:expand(-ratdenom(fraction))],
       block([simp:false],
         numerat/denominat));
   -a/(b-x);
   no_minus(-a/(b-x));
   no_minus(-a*b*c/(b-x*b*f-f));
   ```

I'd expected no_minus(-a/(b-x)) would have returned a/(x-b) but it didn't.

2. I'd like to introduce a new infix operator to denote that two expressions are approximately equal. For instance, if x is
   approximately equal to y. I'd like to note it

   ```
   x =~ y

   infix("=~").
   ```

How to configure the simplifier so that when the input is

```
2*x+3 =~ u+v;  
(%-3)/2;
```

the output is

```
x =~ (u+v-3)/2
```

Answer (score 6):

Well, you can define simplification rules via `tellsimp` (and `tellsimpafter`, `defrule`, and `defmatch`). Maybe this is enough to get started.

```
(%i3) infix ("=~") $
(%i4) matchdeclare ([aa, bb, cc], all) $
(%i5) tellsimp ((aa =~ bb) * cc, (aa * cc) =~ (bb * cc)) $
tellsimp: warning: rule will treat '?mtimes' as noncommutative and nonassociative.
(%i6) tellsimp ((aa =~ bb) + cc, (aa + cc) =~ (bb + cc)) $
tellsimp: warning: rule will treat '?mplus' as noncommutative and nonassociative.
(%i7) (2*x + 3) =~ (u + v);
(%o7) (2*x+3) =~ (v+u)
(%i8) (% - 3)/2;
(%o8) x =~ ((v+u-3)/2)
```

Comment: Thank you, that was really a good start. I just added rbp=80 and lbp=80 to get rid of parenthesis. This is what I needed to solve my infix "approx" operator.;
 infix("=~");
matchdeclare([aa,bb,cc],all);
tellsimp((aa =~ bb)*cc,(aa * cc) =~ (bb * cc));
tellsimp((aa =~ bb)+cc,(aa + cc) =~ (bb + cc));
(2*x+3) =~ (5*y^2+6);
(%-3)/2;
2*x+3 =~ 5*y^2+6;
(%-3)/2;
infix("=~",80,80);
2*x+3 =~ 5*y^2+6;
(%-3)/2;
"=~"(2*x,3*y+4);
%-4;